# Warning when calling method on type id after respondsToSelector if statement

Tags: iphone, ios4, delegates, iphone-sdk-3.0, selector

I'm fairly sure this is a simple issue but it's something that I've been unable to solve.

I am using the `respondsToSelector` method in an if statement to check whether a delegate implements a method. Inside the if statement I then call this selector. Nothing complex. But I get a warning saying the method is not found, ([Screenshot](http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/3655/screenshot20110802at122.png)). If however I include the header file for the class that implements the method, the warning goes away.

I suspect it could be to do with the order the sources are compiled perhaps?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can create arbitrary selectors using `@selector(somethingHere:)`, you cannot call arbitrary methods on an `id` variable without a compiler warning. The compiler will still check that the method/selector you are calling has been defined *somewhere* on a class or category.

You need to include the appropriate header so the compiler knows that there are objects/classes in the system that can respond to that method, otherwise you could mistype a selector and never know about it.

edit:

OK I see now that you are implementing a delegate. In that case you need to declare a protocol with the appropriate methods, and use the type `id<ProtocolName>` for your delegate. Then your class should be declared as implementing that protocol.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide real class behind **id** data type, than write *someProtocol* and than define _delegate in ivars and specify what it implements that protocol.

```
id<someProtocol> _delegate;
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have declared the method in the protocol.